# Show data in Grid from returned model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, model

I have the following lambda in HomeController

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var mainModel = context.Person.Join(context.Car, p => p.personID, c => c.IdPerson, (p,c) => new { pID = p.personID, pName = p.Name, cID = c.carID, cName = c.Name }).ToList();   
            return View(mainModel );
        }
```

In Index.cshtml I set the model and trying to build the Grid

```
@model IEnumerable<CarSln.Models.Car>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div class="row">
        @(Html.Grid(Model).Build(columns =>
            {
              .....................
            })
         )
</div>
```

And the models

```
namespace CarSln.Models
{
    public class Car
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public int carID { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public int idPerson { set; get; }
        public virtual Person Person{ set; get; }
    }
}

namespace CarSln.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public int personID { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }
}
```

I tried various ways, even changed the expression but I can't add the selected columns in the Grid. What am I doing wrong? Is there an issue by having same name columns in the joined tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short yes the same name is going to cause issues. Instead:

**1 - Create a dedicated class that represents the grid data**

```
public class PersonCar
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    public int CarId { get; set; }

    public string CarName { get; set; }
}
```

**2 -  Select to the defined class not an anonymous object**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var mainModel = context.Person.Join(context.Car, p => p.personID, c => c.IdPerson, (p, c) => new PersonCar { PersonId = p.personID, PersonName = p.Name, CarId = c.carID, CarName = c.Name }).ToList();
    return View(mainModel);
}
```

**3 - Use it**

```
@model IEnumerable<CarSln.Models.PersonCar>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div class="row">
        @(Html.Grid(Model).Build(columns =>
            {
               columns.Bound(x => x.PersonId);               
               columns.Bound(x => x.PersonName);               
               columns.Bound(x => x.CarId);               
               columns.Bound(x => x.CarName);               
             })
         )
</div>
```

Hope that helps.